# Is it right to use the auxilary verb do in constructions using could but not can?

Tags: grammar

According to this [Website](https://sentencestack.com/q/could_you_tell_me_how_much_does_a_taxi_cost) it is ok to use the auxiliary verb in the same sentence that uses the modal could but it is marked as [wrong](https://sentencestack.com/q/Can_you_tell_me_how_often_do_the_buses_run) to use it in another sentence which uses a modal as well.

I decided to do further research and I got this:

> The sentence 'Can you tell me how often the buses run?' is correct and
> can be used in written English. You can use it when asking someone,
> either in person or in writing, to provide information about the
> frequency of a bus service. For example, "I'm planning to take the bus
> downtown. Can you tell me how often the buses run?".
> https://app.ludwig.guru/s/could+you+tell+me+how+much+does+a+taxi+cost

Could some one explain why? I am aware that one shouldn't combine the auxiliary verb do with modals but it drew my attention that this search engine says otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confused about when various auxiliary verbs can be used together. There is no prohibition against using multiple such verbs in a single sentence. For example:

> I **could** go to the movies, but I **do** not want to.

However, the modal auxiliary verbs and the auxiliary verb "do" have the following restriction: They must always head predicates. That means that a modal verb will generally not appear in the same predicate as auxiliary "do".

One exception is that a predicate may contain another one, e.g.: "You **must** know that we **do** want you to succeed." Another is that the auxiliary verbs may be in series (though the acceptability of this will vary), e.g.: "We **can** and **do** go swimming every week."

(By the way, the examples on sentencestack.com appear to have other problems. I recommend using a better site to learn English.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a discrepancy between the answers given by the website; there should not be any difference in the two cases, between the use of *could* and *can*.

Both subordinate question-clauses should be in the statement form (SVO), as shown below:

> Could you tell me **how much a taxi [ride] costs**?

> Can you tell me **how often the buses run**?

Answer (score 0):

OK: Could you tell me [question form] how much a taxi costs [declarative statement]

And this: Could you tell me how much a taxi does cost? Is only right in one environment, as follows:

Person 1: *Oh no, that's not the price.* It does not cost that!
Person 2: *Really? Then, can you tell me how much a taxi does cost?*

In the sentence above Person 2 is clarifying a statement by Person 1 but it would not used except in a context like that.

Comment: Did you mean "it would not be used "

Comment: @Quique Yes, it would not be used EXCEPT in a context like that. OR: It would be used in a context like that. Same thing.

Comment: I have already deleted the screenshots and posted the links to the website as you asked, might you check them please?

Comment: @Quique It's ok but next time just take the sentences and get URL from the top. :)

Comment: @Quique Looks OK to me. :)